# React form wrong radio values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I have this modalWindow Component, with a form with a preselected "small" option:**

```
import React from "react";
import pizzaStore from "./stores/PizzaStore";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import cartStore from "./stores/CartStore";
import { action } from "mobx";

function ModalWindowComponent({ activeModal, setActiveModal }: any) {
  const [price, setPrice] = React.useState(pizzaStore.modalProps.price);
  console.log(price);
  const handlePriceChange = (opt: string) => {
    opt === "small"
      ? setPrice(pizzaStore.modalProps.price)
      : opt === "medium"
      ? setPrice(pizzaStore.modalProps.price * 1.5)
      : setPrice(pizzaStore.modalProps.price * 2);
  };
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState("small");

  const setClose = () => {
    setSelectedOption("small");
    setActiveModal(false);
  };

  let fixedSize = pizzaStore.size;
  let size =
    selectedOption === "small"
      ? fixedSize
      : selectedOption === "medium"
      ? fixedSize * 1.5
      : fixedSize * 2;
  let obj = {
    modalName: pizzaStore.modalProps.name,
    modalDesc: pizzaStore.modalProps.description,
    modalSize: size,
    modalPrice: price,
    modalImage: pizzaStore.modalProps.imageUrl,
  };
  return (
    <div
      className={activeModal ? "modal active" : "modal"}
      onClick={() => {
        setActiveModal(false);
        setSelectedOption("small");
      }}
    >
      <div
        className="modal-content"
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.stopPropagation();
        }}
      >
        <div className="modal-content-header">
          <button onClick={() => setClose()}>Close</button>
        </div>
        <img
          src={pizzaStore.modalProps.imageUrl}
          className="modal-content-img"
        />
        <p className="modal-content-pizza-name">{pizzaStore.modalProps.name}</p>
        <p className="modal-content-pizza-desc">
          {pizzaStore.modalProps.description}
        </p>
        <p className="modal-content-pizza-size">{size}см</p>
        <p className="modal-content-pizza-weight">
          {pizzaStore.setWeight(selectedOption)}грамм
        </p>
        <p className="modal-content-pizza-price">{price}Руб.</p>
        <form
          className="modal-content-sizes-form"
          onSubmit={(e: any) => {
            cartStore.handleSubmitForm(e, obj);
          }}
        >
          <label>
            <input
              name="radio-size"
              value="small"
              type="radio"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
                console.log(selectedOption);
                handlePriceChange(selectedOption);
              }}
              checked={selectedOption === "small"}
              className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"
            />
            Маленькая
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              name="radio-size"
              value="medium"
              type="radio"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
                console.log(selectedOption);
                handlePriceChange(selectedOption);
              }}
              checked={selectedOption === "medium"}
              className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"
            />
            Средняя
          </label>
          <label>
            <input
              name="radio-size"
              value="big"
              type="radio"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
                console.log(selectedOption);
              }}
              checked={selectedOption === "big"}
              className="modal-content-sizes-form-option"
            />
            Большая
          </label>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setClose();
              console.log(cartStore.cartItems);
            }}
          >
            Добавить
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default observer(ModalWindowComponent);
```

**The selectedOption state should update when a radiobutton is clicked.**

however, if I try to log in to the console it gives the wrong values.

For example, when you click the medium valued radio button the console logs "small". The other problem is that the price state doesn't update accordingly with the selected option state. I don't quite understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **That's because [state update is batching](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and asynchronous**

You `setSelectedOption` and `handlePriceChange` in the same function which cause the issue that you won't get the latest update `selectedOption`

**So you would use the original value like so:**

```
onChange={(e) => {
  setSelectedOption(e.target.value);
  console.log(selectedOption);
  handlePriceChange(e.target.value);
}}
```

Or having a `useEffect` waiting for `selectedOption` to change before calling `handlePriceChange`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  handlePriceChange(selectedOption);
}, [selectedOption]);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setSelectedOption` actually doesn't change the value of `selectedOption` in your `onChange` handler. My guess is, it always logs the previous value to the console.

To fix this, store `e.target.value` in a variable and log that.